# Colocar If no Where

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte `Where`

```
  WHERE 1 = 1
    AND (0 = 0  OR 1 = 1)
    inicio do if
    AND (2 = 2  OR 3 = 3)
    fim do if
```

Como eu faria o if?

A ideia é que venha um valor por parâmetro e se aquele valor satisfazer o `if` eu adicione o `and`.

Comment: Esse problema pode ser solucionado de diversas formas, tente prover mais informações para achar a ideal. Como é a condição do seu `if` a variavel vem de um procedure? ela é booleana? você pode ressolver com uma query dinâmica, com um case ou até mesmo com comparações e operadores lógicos.

Comment: @user90864 Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem diversas soluções, vou citar 3 delas.

Nos exemplos abaixo verifico se a variável `@idUsuario` é nula, se não for efetuo a busca do nome do usuário com o `idUsuario` correspondente a variável.

Alternativa com  [CASE WHEN](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @idUsuario INT 
SET @idUsuario = 1

SELECT 
    Nome 
FROM
    Usuario
WHERE 
    idUsuario = (
        CASE WHEN @idUsuario IS NULL THEN
            idUsuario 
        ELSE
            @idUsuario 
        END
    )
```

Alternativa com **comparação de valor** e utilização do operador lógico [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188361(v=sql.120).aspx) para formar o filtro:

```
DECLARE @idUsuario INT 
SET @idUsuario = 1

SELECT 
    Nome
FROM
    Usuario
WHERE 
    (@idUsuario IS NULL OR idUsuario = @idUsuario)
```

Alternativa com **query dinâmica**:

```
DECLARE @query varchar(MAX)

DECLARE @idUsuario INT 
SET @idUsuario = 1

SET @query = 'SELECT Nome FROM Usuario'
IF @idUsuario IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @query = @query + ' WHERE idUsuario =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @idUsuario)
END 

EXEC (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para condições, utiliza-se a expressão [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Nesta query: CASO a condição de `1` seja igual `1` a saída será `1`, sendo contrário `0`.

Utilizando case você poderá utilizar váriaveis como também colunas, p.x:

```
SELECT CASE @param WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT CASE table.column WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```