# Como fazer um select dentro de uma condição?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Como posso fazer para criar um *script* em *SQL* onde é executado um *SELECT*, e conforme o resultado de uma coluna deste primeiro, executa uma determinada condição de uma outra tabela?

exemplo:

```
select * from tabela as t
SE t.saldo = 0 entao WHERE t2.outracondicao = 'condicao'
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Colocar If no Where](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262558/colocar-if-no-where)

Comment: Poderia colocar a estrutura das tabelas na sua questão? Não haverá já questões idênticas à sua aqui no SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela AS t
WHERE (t.saldo = 0 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM tabela2 AS t2 
                   WHERE t2.outracondicao = 'condicao'))
  -- OR t.saldo <> 0
```

Quando o saldo for igual a zero, só será executada a pesquisa se a condição da segunda tabela for atendida (como você não mostrou a estrutura das tabelas, mantive na resposta as *"informações"* que estão na pergunta).
O trecho comentado (`--OR t.saldo <> 0`) pode ser usado, caso você precise. Ele executará a consulta caso o saldo seja diferente de zero.

---

Outra alternativa é que a validação seja feita *antes* da consulta. Se a validação em `tabela2` independe de `tabela`, pode ser feito assim:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tabela2 AS t2 WHERE t2.outracondicao = 'condicao')
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM tabela AS t
    WHERE t.saldo = 0 
END
```

---

Conforme sugestão de [@rbz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/92908/rbz), criei um **[exemplo online](http://rextester.com/AVFLCF22370)** para validação.

Comment: Mas se o select não é recursivo, como ele ficará "lendo" o valor do saldo, e "refazendo" o filtro (where)?

Comment: No caso, `saldo` só é validado se a condição que ele precisa da `tabela2` existir.. então traria todos os valores com saldo igual a zero  (se `t2.outracondicao = 'condicao'`)

Comment: Sim, mas o `t.saldo` é da tabela principal. A cada tupla, fará um WHERE? E ainda assim aqui `SELECT 1` ficou confuso. Por favor, faz um SQLFiddle que eu estou com um nó na cabeça! ahahah

Comment: Foi uma boa ideia. _fiddle_ criado.. resposta alterada ;]

Comment: Nossa cara, agora só que eu vi `t2.outracondicao`. Por isso que vocês estão fazendo `JOIN`... Até apaguei meu outro comentário na pergunta! hahaha valeu!

Answer (score 3):

nesse caso, se você tiver dois campos em comum dentro das duas tabelas, pode utilizar o `WHERE IN`

Digamos que há o campo ID na tabela2 que também está presente na tabela1. Você poderia fazer do seguinte modo:

`SELECT * FROM tabela2 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tabela1 WHERE saldo='0')`

Essa query irá buscar todos os registros da tabela2 que também estão presentes na tabela1, mas apenas com saldo 0.

Comment: Lucas, acho que um ponto diferente da sua resposta é que você retorna tudo da `tabela2`, mas na pergunta ele pede `select * from tabela` (tabelas diferentes). Além disso, se `id` for um _código_ (preenchimento manual/controlado), a comparação é correta; porém se for um _contador_ (_identity_), possivelmente serão diferentes nas duas tabelas (um não corresponderá ao outro)

Comment: rLinhares, sim, seria interessante sabermos a estrutura das tabelas, como elas se conectam (e se realmente o fazem) e qual a aplicação dos dados. Obrigado pela observação.

Answer (score 2):

Esse modo poderá te ajudar:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tabela t
JOIN tabela2 t2
    ON t2.id = t.id
WHERE 
    t2.outracondicao = (CASE
                        WHEN t.saldo = 0
                            THEN 'condicao'
                        END)
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem a solução, achei meio confuso o join. De qualquer forma, se o saldo for diferente de zero, ele tentaria comparar o `t2.outracondicao` com `NULL`, não?!

Comment: Isso, ele compararia com NULL, para trazer tudo é necessário fazer um ELSE t2.outracondicao.

WHERE t2.outracondicao = (CASE 
                                                WHEN t.saldo = 0 THEN 'condicao'
                                                ELSE t2.outracondicao                        
                                           END)